# .htaccess - check if part of URL is missing - 301 redirect for ajax URLS

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have made a copy of a wordpress site and set it up on localhost (WAMP), everything works well apart from all of the AJAX calls as the URLs have not been updated.

I need the urls to be in the following format:    http://localhost/mysite/dashboard/ but instead they have the /mysite/ part missing ie.  http://localhost/dashboard/

I assumed this could be resolved by doing a 301 redirect in the same way a none www domain is redirected to a www.   I have tried the below but it doesn't do anything:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^/mysite/\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/mysite/$1 [R=301,L]


---------------------HTACCESS FILE----------------------------
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L]
RewriteRule !^mysite/ /mysite/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That rule should be:

```
RewriteRule !^mysite/ /mysite%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

`%{HTTP_HOST}` variable only matches domain name in the request not the `REQUEST_URI`.

Comment: This isn't working for me.  Perhaps other rules are conflicting?  I have pasted the whole of the htaccess file above

Comment: In that case you will need this rule in the .htaccess in the parent directory of `mysite`. If that `.htaccess` doesn't exist then you need to create it.